# BCP Export - Empty String

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have a view that I need to keep as is since it is called all over the place. So it cannot be modified.
The view returns some columns with an empty string.

```
select col1, col2, col3, '' as col4, '' as col5 from myTable
```

This is how I initiate my BCP command to export that view to a csv file. `@FileLocation` and `@FileName` are set beforehand.

```
declare @SQL varchar(8000)
set @SQL = 'select col1, col2, col3, '''' as col4, '''' as col5 from myTable'
set @SQL = 'bcp "' + @SQL + '" queryout "' + @FileLocation + @FileName + '" -c -t; -q -T"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @SQL
```

The file gets created without problems but `col4` and `col5` are shown as "`NUL`" in Notepad++.
How do I need to modify my BCP command to export empty strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading all the comments, it seems that there is no way to accomplish what I want. I ended up duplicating the view and populated the empty fields in a way that worked for `bcp`.
Very annoying but apparently the only doable option.

Answer (score 0):

bcp.exe has an odd behaviour that flips `NULL` and `''` around during out/queryout:

> When extracting data, the bcp utility represents an empty string as a null and a null string as an empty string.

REF: [bcp Utility - Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)

Try using the following query instead:

```sql
select col1, col2, col3, null as col4, null as col5 from myTable
```

Comment: Thanks, yes. I know. When I make the column value NULL, it will work. However, as I said I cannot change the query since it is a view that is used across the board.

Comment: I need to know play with the bcp command. There is a „-k“ parameter but I haven’t figured out how to use it here.

Comment: @Daniel No one said you have to change the view. You change the query that you use as the source in your BCP command to simply translate the empty strings to NULL - something like `SELECT ..., NULLIF(col4, '') AS col4, ... from myView` (and note that your example uses "myTable" - let's not add confusion). Since you know those columns are string constants, you could ignore them and replace with your own constants (at some risk).

Comment: Yes, I agree. That is a bit confusing. 
`select col1, col2, col3, null as col4, null as col5 from myTable` is the definition of the view. That definition is much bigger in reality - about 100 columns.
So when I call my view in the query, I would use `select * from myView` since it would be to messy to write down each column. 
Anyhow, is my understanding correct that I cannot control the output of empty string vs. Null in the BCP command? If that's the case I might have to duplicate the view and change those empty string columns to Null columns but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @Daniel You could choose _not_ to use bcp.exe for this task. There's no reason you couldn't use PowerShell, C# or any other SQL-capable external process to generate your ;-delimited files.

Comment: That’s true. However, for simplicity reasons I wanted to keep everything in one stored procedure.

Comment: I don't see the simplicity... you're already not doing that by shelling out to a command shell to execute bcp.exe which then creates another SQL connection back into the database to execute your code. Each to their own.